# How can I connect multiple microphones to my computer (more than 4) and process the outputs independently?

Tags: sound, source-separation

I am trying to create something like a heat map for sounds originating in a classroom to study the discussions inside the classroom. For this I am instaling directional microphones in various parts of the classroom and inputing the amplitude of sounds captured by them. I need to take the inputs from the microphones and process all of them separately. What hardware/software should I use for this?

PS: I have a mixer board but it'll give me a single channel input. I want separate inputs from all the microphones

Comment: possible duplicate of [Audio interface or External sound card?](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/11472/audio-interface-or-external-sound-card)

Comment: This question is not about signal processing, but rather about usage of specific equipment.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of application is that and what kind of microphones (dynamic, condenser, home-made electret ones) solutions can be different. Are you going to process everything in real-time or to make your analysis offline?

- If your microphones doesn't require Phantom power and can be plugged into mic-in, then you can buy few of cheapest USB sound cards, plug them to your laptop, run your linux, create virtual device with JACK and you can record. **But** do not expect to run in real time - most likely there will occur lot's of problems with synchronisation (had them on my own).  So it is good for not a real-time application. Here is some article about that: [Using Multiple Devices with JACK](http://www.penguinproducer.com/Blog/2011/11/using-multiple-devices-with-jack/) and topic from [Audacity guys](http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=56492).
- If you want to use microphones that require a phantom power, then you should buy/borrow some 4+ channel USB/FireWire audio interface. You plug it into your computer and record whatever you want. No problems with latency, everything is synchronised. What program can you use? That's up to you - on linux I suggest Ardour on Windows I am using REAPER a lot. But for scientific applications just use the ASIO drivers and record tracks.